# Mac OS X 10.9.5

Tags: macos, batch-file

I need to run a .bat file on my Mac, the file is a portable version of R called RCommander and I need to run it because it comes with all packages I need to work with and I have problems to download some of these packages with the R Version I already have on my computer (because they are not available for that Version, but there is no other Version for mac and so on...).
I would be really thankful for a stepwise explanation of what to type into the terminal to run the file. If that's of use:  the file is called RCommander.bat

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to run a .bat on OS X. BAT files are Windows only. Try looking for a .sh, as it is the equivalent for UNIX based systems (OS X included).

EDIT: After a little bit of reading, look into CRAN, it might provide you with what you need.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I hoped that it is possible because on some websites people commented instructions like here http://www.alvinpoh.com/how-to-make-and-run-batch-files-in-terminal-in-mac-osx/     it didn't work for me but I thought maybe I used the commands wrong